# Firebase User UID not matching Auth UID

Tags: firebase

I'm new to using Firebase (I'm using react-redux-firebase, but not sure if that's relevant to this question). I'm having an issue using these standard auth rules:

```
{
   "rules": {
      "users": {
         "$uid": {
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is user UID as shown in the Firebase Authentication dashboard:

[image]

But if I print out the data associated with the profile/account, I get this UID:

[image]

Because of this mismatch, the logged in user is unable to read or write to the firebase instance.

[image]

Why is there a mismatch in UIDs? How can I solve this issue?

UPDATE:

It looks like the `1091103…` UID is provider-specific and not relevant in this case? Can't confirm that for sure.

This may be the actual auth UID (I'm new to this, so still trying to figure out what's what):

[image]

In this case, this UID matches what is seen in the Firebase console. If they match, then what would be the cause of the permission denied errors?

ANOTHER UPDATE:

Here's the user node. You can see the UID as the key:

[image]

Comment: i thinks that is `Provider-specific UID` form google sign in. not auth UID

Comment: check under `users` you have the correct `auth UID` listed, otherwise you are saving wrong UID to `users` database

Comment: It appears that they match. Looking through the Firebase database there are no mismatches of UIDs. So in that case, I'm not sure why I'm getting permission denied errors. Updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: how is your users collection looks? or provide the code for writing users.

Comment: are you using `.push` to write to `users`?

Comment: No, I'm using `.login({ provider: 'google' })`, which seems to handle everything automatically, such as saving the UID. As noted in one of the screenshots above, you can see the correct UID in the Firebase dashboard.

Comment: its not work that way, in database rules you are checking auth.uid with a value stored in database under users node.

Answer (score 0):

This is the rule you can do right now

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

if you want to check like below

```
{
   "rules": {
      "users": {
         "$uid": {
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

you need to store the users to realtime database while register. with their `auth.uid` as key.

Comment: I'm using an external authorization provider (google, as seen in one of the screenshots). According to the docs I've been reading — "Firebase creates the user automatically". If user creation / registration happens automatically, how am I suppose to "store the users to realtime database"? The provider didn't set a UID in the user's row in the realtime database.

Comment: I added another update to my question that includes a screenshot of the user node.