# Firebase auth uid not interpreting the actual value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I see a similar issue in [Firebase User UID not matching Auth UID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46960694/firebase-user-uid-not-matching-auth-uid), 
however mine is slightly different, instead of comparing the key in the path I am trying to compare the value with the auth.uid.
It looks like a bug according to my testing, I tried to log it with Firebase, but Andres replied that comparing the data values is not the way to work the rules.

The data is stored with the Key "id" which has the value 455, if I hard code 455 in the rules, it works fine. If I reference "äuth.id" it fails. I can tell auth.id is failing because if I test with a different function such as hasChild('auth.id') it works fine, I am using this as a workaround for now.This is on the Realtime database with rules v2.

In all tests I am trying to do a read at /test

Data:

```
  test
    |-677
    |  |-jf:"golf"
    |-ff:"tennis"
    |-id: 455
```

Auth token :

```
{
   "provider": "anonymous",
   "uid": "455"
}
```

Rule that fails which should have passed :

```
read: "data.child('id').val()==auth.id"
```

Rule that works hard coded:

```
read: "data.child('id').val()==455"
```

Rules that works indicating the value in auth.id is correct

```
read: "data.child('id').val==455 && root.child('test').hasChild(auth.uid)"
read:  root.child('test').hasChild(auth.uid)"
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4scAS.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVgKU.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjYsg.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTW6x.png